# Docker Compose Unsupported Option 'additional_contexts'

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers, command-line-interface

I am getting the error:

```bash
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.api.build contains unsupported option: 'additional_contexts'
```

When I try to run `docker-compose` commands but, they are supported: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#additional_contexts

EDIT 1:

My compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile
      context: ./
      additional_contexts:
        - data=./backend
      args:
        - ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
    container_name: api
    environment:
      - MODE=$MODE
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - 9999:9999
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: always
```

EDIT 2:

Output `docker-compose version`:

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.11.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Would be helpful to get your Docker Compose file

Comment: @tal-rofe I'm do this right now, thank you.

Comment: docker-compose version might help as well

Comment: You declare `version: '3.8'`, but [Compose file version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) doesn't support that option (and version 1 of the Compose tool actually honors the declared file version).

Comment: @david-maze In fact, as I said in the comment on the answer that I marked as resolved, I updated the docker-compose version and the problem no longer exists. The problem is not actually the version of the docker compose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to upgrade docker-compose.

Support for additional_context has been added with version 2.17.0

see https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#2170

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly it, the outdated compose version. I had to download the [standalone](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/standalone/) version from the website manually and now everything works. It actually surprises me a little that this package in my distro is not updated (I use Debian SID).